# How to re sequence grid in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I have a requirement where I have many routes say **Route1, Route2, Route3, Route4 ...** etc in a `grid` with `rowexpander`, as shown below :

```
+----------+
|  Routes  |
+----------+
| + Route1 |
| + Route2 |
| + Route3 |
| + Route4 |
+----------+
```

On expanding the `grid` each route will contain **stops** within them as follows :

```
+----------+
|  Routes  |
+----------+
| - Route1 |
| -------- |
|    Stop1 |
|    Stop2 |
|    Stop3 |
| -------- |
| - Route2 |
| -------- |
|    Stop4 |
|    Stop5 |
|    Stop6 |
| -------- |
| - Route3 |
| -------- |
|    Stop7 |
|    Stop8 |
|    Stop9 |
| -------- |
| + Route4 |
+----------+
```

These **stops** can be re sequenced within a **route** (like Route1's Stop1 can be dragged and dropped after Stop2) and **stops** can be also re sequenced across **routes** ( like Stop4 from Route2 can be dragged and dropped after Stop7 of Route3 ). The resultant `grid` will look something like this after the above operations :

```
+----------+
|  Routes  |
+----------+
| - Route1 |
| -------- |
|    Stop2 |
|    Stop1 |
|    Stop3 |
| -------- |
| - Route2 |
| -------- |
|    Stop5 |
|    Stop6 |
| -------- |
| - Route3 |
| -------- |
|    Stop7 |
|    Stop4 |
|    Stop8 |
|    Stop9 |
| -------- |
| + Route4 |
+----------+
```

I am relatively new to `ExtJS , all my tries to achieve this have gone in vain. Is there any way to achieve this? Code illustrated example will be greatly helpful.

Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: rowexpander is mainly intended for text. Have you looked into Treegrid? It supports these operations more or less out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alexander . Can we do it without the row expander ? i.e load the stops of all routes in expanded form and then re sequence .

Comment: Have you tried to find out what a treegrid is?